# NSUserDefaults removeObjectForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I've noticed some unexpected behavior with this method, and was wondering if anyone had any insight. When I call `removeObjectForKey`, I have noticed that `[setObject: obj ForKey: key]` is actually called behind the scenes. I'm running into problems because I have overwritten this method `(setObject forKey`) for `NSUserDefaults`.

The documentation of `removeObjectForKey` says:

> Removing a default has no effect on the value returned by the `objectForKey:` method if the same key exists in a domain that precedes the standard application domain in the search list.

What exactly is an application domain, and could this be the reason why `setObject` is being called? I'm confused because I'm trying to remove from the `NSUserDefaults` `NSDictionary`, not set an object to it.

Comment: My guess is that removeObjectForKey just calls setObjectForKey with `null`.

Comment: Great call! That would make a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't override `setObject:forKey` for `NSUserDefaults`. Seems like a really bad idea. For what it's worth, `setObject:forKey` is probably being called with a nil value to delete the key.